# Using the st.write() , st.text or st.markdown() in streamlit is displaying None

Tags: python, pandas

The code is given as -

```
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import pandas as pd

def recommend(movie):
    movie_index = movies[movies['title'] == movie].index[0]
    distances = similarity[movie_index]
    movies_list = sorted(list(enumerate(distances)), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[1:6]

    recommended_movies = []
    for i in movies_list:
        recommended_movies.append(print(movies.iloc[i[0]].title))
    return recommended_movies

movies_dict = pickle.load(open('movie_dict.pkl', 'rb'))
movies = pd.DataFrame(movies_dict)

similarity = pickle.load(open('similarity.pkl', 'rb'))

st.title('Movie Recommender System')

selected_movie_name = st.selectbox(
'Hey ! Wanna watch a movie ? Tell us the last movie you watched -',
movies['title'].values)

if st.button('Recommend'):
    recommendations = recommend(selected_movie_name)
    for i in recommendations :
        st.write(i)  #### This is what i'm talking about
```

i tried other alternatives such as st.text or st.markdown but none of them are working
its showing none each and every time

Comment: `recommended_movies.append(print(movies.iloc[i[0]].title))` doesn't do what you think it does. `print` displays things to the user, and returns `None`. Thus, `recommended_movies` ends up like `[None, None, None....]`. It's not Streamlit's fault - it is displaying exactly what you tell it to display.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, you need to append without calling print such as:

```
recommended_movies.append(movies.iloc[i[0]].title)
```